# Find the numbers of ordered arrays $(x_1,...,x_{100})$ such that 2017 divides both their sum and their sum of squares

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers, prime-numbers

Find the numbers of ordered array $(x_1,\dots,x_{100})$ that satisfies the following conditions:

$1)$ $2017\mid x_1+\dots+x_{100}$

$2)$ $2017\mid x_1^2+x_2^2+\dots+x_{100}^2 $

$3)$ $x_1,\dots,x_{100}\in\{1,2,\dots,2017\}$

Here's all i did :

Let $\omega = e^{2 \pi i / 2017}$. Note that :

$$\sum_{0\le a,b\le (2017-1)}  \omega^{a(x_1+x_2+..+x_{100})+b(x_1^2+x_2^2+...+x_{100}^2)} = 2017^2$$  if $ (x_1;x_2;...x_{100})$ satisfies the conditions and :

$$\sum_{0\le a,b\le (2017-1)}  \omega^{a(x_1+x_2+..+x_{100})+b(x_1^2+x_2^2+...+x_{100}^2)} = 0$$  if $ (x_1;x_2;...x_{100})$ doesn't satisfy the conditions.

Symbol: $X$ is the set of all tuples $(x_1, x_2,,...,x_{100})$ , $Y$ is the set of all tuples$(x_1, x_2,,...,x_{100})$ satisfying the condition.

$$\Rightarrow |Y| = \frac{1}{2017^2}  \sum_{0\le a,b\le (2017-1)} \sum_{(x_1;x_2;...;x_{100})\in X} \omega^{a(x_1+x_2+..+x_{100})+b(x_1^2+x_2^2+...+x_{100}^2)} $$

$$\Rightarrow |Y| = \frac{1}{2017^2}  \sum_{0\le a,b\le (2017-1)} \left(\sum_{1 \le x \le 2017} \omega^{ax^2+bx} \right)^{100}$$

Let $$G(a,b) = \sum_{1 \le x \le 2017} \omega^{ax^2+bx} $$

Case $1 : a=0 ;b=0 \Rightarrow G(0,0) = 2017$

Case $2: a=0 ;b >0 \Rightarrow G(0,b) =\sum_{1 \le x \le 2017} \omega^{bx} =0$

Case$3$$:a>0 ;b =0 \Rightarrow G(a,0) =\sum_{1 \le x \le 2017} \omega^{ax^2} \Rightarrow |G(a,0)|^2 = (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2} }.2017 \Rightarrow |G(a,0)|^{100} = 2017^{50} $

Case $4 : a>0 ;b >0 $

In this case, I'm very stuck, I don't know how to solve it! I look forward to getting help from everyone. Thanks very much!

Comment: Your $G(a,b)$ is a quadratic Gauss sum. Search for that phrase, and you'll find ways to evaluate it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_Gauss_sum#Generalized_quadratic_Gauss_sums  . But they don't teach me how to prove the properties, can you give me another document?

Comment: Is that the only link that comes up when you type *quadratic Gauss sum* into Google? or into the search box on this page?

Comment: @GerryMyerson  Yes. Well, I couldn't find anything more specific than that. I have searched the box of this page but it does not contain information on how to prove the properties.

Answer (score 1):

Completed answer. It is easier *not* to separate the case $a>0,b=0.$

Basically, complete the square.

If $a>0,$ let $\omega_0=\omega^{(4a)^{-1}},$ where $(4a)^{-1}$ is calculate modulo $2017.$ This can be done because $2017$ is an odd prime.

Then $$\omega^{ax^2+bx}=\omega_0^{(2ax+b)^2}\omega_0^{-b^2}.$$

Now $(2ax+b)^2$ covers all the perfect squares. So you get:

$$G(a,b)=\omega^{-(4a)^{-1}b^2}\sum_{x=0}^{2016}\omega^{(4a)^{-1}x^2}.$$

I the remaining sum only depends on whether $a$ is a square, modulo $2017.$

Specifically:

$$G(a,b)=\left(\frac a{2017}\right)\omega^{(4a)^{-1}b^2}\sum_{x=0}^{2016}\omega^{x^2}$$ where $(a/2017)$ is the Legendre symbol.

We don’t really need to know $S=\sum_{x=0}^{2016}\omega^{x^2},$ just that it is constant.

---

The generating function version of your approach is a little simpler. Let $$f(x,y)=\sum_{i=0}^{2016}x^iy^{i^2}$$

Then the sum of the coefficients of $x^ny^m$ in $f^{100}(x,y)$ where $m,n$ are both divisible by $2017$ is:

$$\frac{1}{2017^2}\sum_{a,b=0}^{2017} f^{100}(\omega^b,\omega^a)$$
This is equivalent to your approach, because:
$$G(a,b)=f(\omega^b,\omega^a)$$

So when $a\neq 0,$ $$G(a,b)=\left(\frac a{2017}\right)\omega^{(4a)^{-1}b^2} S$$ for some constant $S.$

So $$
\begin{align} 
\sum_{b=0}^{2016} G(a,b)^{100}&=S^{100}\sum_{b=0}^{2016}\omega^{25a^{-1}b^2}\\&=S^{100}\left(\left(\frac a{2017}\right)S\right)
\end{align} 
$$
So:

$$\sum_{a=1}^{2106}\sum_{b=0}^{2016} G(a,b)^{100}=0$$

This means your total is simply $$2017^{98}.$$

---

A quick way to see this for $4$ instead of $100,$ and $5$ instead of $2017,$ then counting $a+b+c+d, a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$ divisible by $5,$ we should get $5^{4-2}=25.$

And we do, $(0,0,0,0)$ and the $24$ permutations of $(1,2,3,4).$

For $p=17,$ a computer program counted $(a,b,c,d)$ tuples as $17^2.$

Comment: Hey , why $$G(a,b)=f(\omega^b,\omega^a)$$

So when $a\neq 0,$ $$G(a,b)=\left(\frac a{2017}\right)\omega^{(4a)^{-1}b^2} S$$ for some constant $S.$ ?? Can you say clearer ?

Answer (score 0):

[This didn't work out like I thought it would. Might delete if I can't fix this.]

**Hint:** How many solutions are there to the following system of equations $ \pmod{2017}$?

$\begin{cases} a+b = x   \\
a^2 + b^2 = y   \\ \end{cases}$

Claim: There are

- 1 solution when $y = x^2 / 2$
- 2 solutions when $ y = x^2/2 + 2k^2$ for some $k \neq 0$
- 0 solutions when $ y $ is not twice a quadratic residue.

On average, there is 1 solution, if $y$ is uniformly distributed.

---

Now, for any sequence of $ x_1, x_2, \ldots x_{98}$, relate the number ways can we complete the sequence to satisfy the original conditions to the above system of equations.

[This claim is not true, like in the $n = 4, p = 5 $ case.]  Claim: Consider all sequences where $ \sum_{i=1}^{98} x_i = - x$. Then, the distribution of $ \sum_{i=1}^{98} x_i^2$ is uniform.

Corollary: There are $ 2017^{97}$ sequences where $ \sum_{i=1}^{98} x_i = - x$.
Since the distribution of $\sum x_i^2$ is uniform, this tells us that there are $ 2017^{97}$ solutions to the original system under this condition.

Corollary: Summing over all values of $x$, there are $2017^{98}$ solutions to the original system.

Comment: Can you say clearer ? I can't imagine the idea

Comment: @abcccccc Sadly, I don't think this works. I laid out how I thought it could work out, but the distribution part doesn't seem "obvious" to me.

Comment: Help me please  !